# Authenticate against Active Dir on remote machine using C#

Tags: authentication, azure, active-directory

How can i access Active directory on remote machine. 
I have created a win server 2008 R2 with AD installed in Azure. Hostname: MyVMachine, DNS: myapp.cloudapp.net. I can access the machine using remote desktop connection from my laptop.

I want to authenticate users against that AD. Should i use ContextType.Domain or ContextType.Machine and what about LDAP, how to constrauct it in order to contact that AD?  This code is in a WCF service application in my laptop. The following is not working:

```
        using (PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "LDAP://MyVMachine.testenv.local/ou=Users,dc=testenv,dc=local"))
        {
            // validate the credentials
            bool b = pc.ValidateCredentials("Administrator", "password");
            return true;
        }
```

i want here to authenticaate the user Administrator whiich i see exsists in Users node in testenv.local node i AD machine.

with this code i am getting "The server could not be contacted." with principalServerDownExceptioan.

I need help please.

Thank you all

My AD Machine in Azure:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your current requested scenario is not possible, nor is supported. The only supported option as of today (and it is still in PREVIEW) is [Active Directory REPLIC](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/networking/replica-domain-controller/)A in the Azure. Which means you have to have your on-premises AD and use Azure ones as replica.

In order to even to the replica, you must configure an [Azure Virtual Network](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/networking/add-a-vm-to-a-virtual-network/) to establish a VPN between your on-premises machines and Windows Azure Virtual Network.

***My guess and speculation***:

One of possible reasons for that (my guess) is that currently in Windows Azure Virtual Networks, although defining the Subnets your self, all the VMs **must** have DHCP allocated IP addresses. While a master Domain Controller must have a static IP address.

**UPDATE**

If you want to use just the LDAP functionality as described in `LDAP://MyVMachine.testenv.local/` you have to open the LDAP ports in both Windows Server Firewll and Windows Azure Virtual Machine Input Endpoints (configurable from the new portal, when you select the VM there is "Endpoints" menu item on top). Which shall be [TCP protocol on (default) port 389 or 636 for SSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightweight_Directory_Access_Protocolhttp://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightweight_Directory_Access_Protocol). And you must also install the LDAP feature of the server and configure it. But these are more AD/LDAP specifics, which if you don't know better ask on [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/).